# Missing gradleIdentityPath on Error when run Idea Plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have write a demo Idea Plugin, when i try to run this Plugin.
This "Missing gradleIdentityPath on plugin-demo" Error come out.

My idea version info is:
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023

My plugin project like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LyPm.png)
build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
  id("java")
  id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.13.3"
}

group = "cn.melonkid"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central/'}
  maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/' }
  maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google/' }
  maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter/'}
  maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin'}
  //    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3'
  testRuntimeOnly    'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3'
  testRuntimeOnly    'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.3'
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.3'
}

intellij {
  version = '2023.1'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
  options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:unchecked', '-Xlint:deprecation', '-parameters']
}

patchPluginXml {
  sinceBuild = '231'
  untilBuild = '232.*'
}
```

I have no idea to fix this now.

Comment: Please try updating to newer IDE version. Will it help?

Comment: It might be an issue that was fixed in one of the recent versions of IDEA (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317045/Resync-Gradle-projects-throws-Missing-gradleIdentityPath). If the problem persists, would you be able to share your Project?